# Regular expression and extracting a value

Tags: regex, scala, gatling

I need to get hold oif the |value| below:

```
{"token":"<input name=\"__RequestVerificationToken\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"KhWUxVIL697p18Gm3T1b4pCmXjK7iQujsJieYiLOKcKmKbdvC55kgaqg4G-uGqeUzmV3x6EMAV_ejPHe-Ok2kFqnjzVmvZmHySMpwKzGvq01\" />"}
```

What kind of regular expression would match that?

I have tried to us this:

```
.check(regex("input name='__RequestVerificationToken' type='hidden' value='([A-Za-z0-9+=/'-'_]+?)'").saveAs("token")))
```

But it does not match.

Also using a regex tester does not get me anywhere, please help me.

Comment: you're trying to catch the "\" escape characters?

Comment: I don't know the language you are working in, but it must be something like `/value=(?:"|')(.*?)(?:"|')/`

Comment: Why are you using single quotes when your example has backslashed double quotes?

Comment: Please review the [regex tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) and update your question accordingly.  Thanks.

Comment: Scala it is... No did not work...

Comment: Your example text has double quotes and your example regex has single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
regex("<input.+__RequestVerificationToken.+value=\\?(\"|\')(.+)\\?(\"|\').+>")
```

It can be made shorter, but I was not sure how actual example string looks (does it have escape chars at once, does it use single or double qoutes).

Comment: Using:     .check(regex("""<input.+__RequestVerificationToken.+value=\\?(\"|\')(.+)\\?(\"|\').+>""").saveAs("token")))

just prints this to my console: "    "
I have a print to console scala function to debug...

Comment: Why did you add so many double qoutes at the beginning and end?

Comment: I have been playing with a reggae translator, but I don´t know how to say 'keep the value in between'


I have used this so far:


    value=\\.([A-Za-z0-9+=/\-\_])+(\\")



But that gives me all this:


    value=\"foqisp--sK_JtpZ3Ks4CTmX-    YIev36x5vcXd_GcIszkM011Hk_WI5rsWI090u1NlaKruo_Ji9M401kmvcCDX    SmEpx9dIjV4wFum9T3QTllU1\" 


How can I decrease to only extract:


    foqisp--sK_JtpZ3Ks4CTmX-    YIev36x5vcXd_GcIszkM011Hk_WI5rsWI090u1NlaKruo_Ji9M401kmvcCDX    SmEpx9dIjV4wFum9T3QTllU1

Comment: @Grengas  the triple quote in scala are used to create a string that does not need any escaping and allows for multiple lines

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the string in your question is exactly the way it appears, with escaped double quotes  **\"**  etc.
here is the code:

```
    val regexGroupExtractor = """.*value=\\"(.*)\\".*""".r
    val regexGroupExtractor(e) = s

    // e == "KhWUxVIL697p18Gm3T1b4pCmXjK7iQujsJieYiLOKcKmKbdvC55kgaqg4G-uGqeUzmV3x6EMAV_ejPHe-Ok2kFqnjzVmvZmHySMpwKzGvq01"
```

In general with regex it is often helpful to think of the pattern in reverse: instead of specifying what is included, specify what is not. In your case there is no need to specify which characters are "in" inside the (), instead focus on where the part you want starts and ends. Specifically in your example - quotes are outside the string you want, in fact the quotes are exactly the edges, so in my regex I capture whatever it is between them.